# php check current date in time&date range

Tags: php, date, time, range

I need to check the current date in date and time range.

```
if(date('N') >= 5 OR date('N') <= 6 AND date('H:i:s') >= "18:00:00" AND date("H:i:s") <= "08:00:00")
{
    $orderAvailable = 1;
}
else 
{
    $orderAvailable = 0;
}
```

I need to disable order from Thursday 18:00 until Saturday 12:00. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: You probably meant to put the `OR` conditions into parentheses.

Comment: I think you should use parenteses to clear your condition

Answer (score 1):

In other words: you want to deactivate orders on

- Thursday from 6 p.m.,
- all Friday
- Saturday until 12 p.m.

That as a condition:

```
if(
 (date('N') == 4 AND date('Hi') >= 1800)
  OR (date('N') == 5)
  OR (date('N') == 6 AND date('Hi') < 1200)
) {
  $orderAvailable = 0;
}
else {
  $orderAvailable = 1;
}
```

That was the understandable solution. The short version:

```
$orderAvailable =  !(date('NHi') >= 41800 AND date('NHi') < 61200);
//true or false
```